# Sharp package Heroku deployment issue

Tags: node.js, heroku, sharp

I'm deploying my NodeJs app to Heroku. No issues running the app with nodemon locally.

However when I'm trying to push to Heroku Master, seems like "[sharp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sharp)" package is causing an issue:

> remote: -----> Installing dependencies
>
> remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
>
> remote:
>
> remote:        > sharp@0.22.0 install
>   /tmp/build_4cfeda2379ea362c72ac083b57638cce/node_modules/sharp
>
> remote:        > (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy &&
>   prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
>
> remote:
>
> remote:        info sharp Downloading
>   https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.7.4/libvips-8.7.4-linux-x64.tar.gz
>
> remote:
>   /tmp/build_4cfeda2379ea362c72ac083b57638cce/node_modules/sharp/install/libvips.js:86
>
> remote:                  throw new Error(`Status
>   ${response.statusCode}`);
>
> remote:                  ^
>
> remote:
>
> remote:        Error: Status 403
>
> remote:            at
>   /tmp/build_4cfeda2379ea362c72ac083b57638cce/node_modules/sharp/install/libvips.js:86:17
>
> remote:            at f
>   (/tmp/build_4cfeda2379ea362c72ac083b57638cce/node_modules/once/once.js:25:25)
>
> remote:            at ClientRequest.protocol.request.res
>   (/tmp/build_4cfeda2379ea362c72ac083b57638cce/node_modules/simple-get/index.js:63:5)
>
> remote:            at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:277:13)
>
> remote:            at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:189:13)
>
> remote:            at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as
>   onIncoming] (_http_client.js:556:21)
>
> remote:            at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete
>   (_http_common.js:109:17)
>
> remote:            at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:442:20)
>
> remote:            at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:189:13)
>
> remote:            at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
>
> remote:        make: Entering directory
>   '/tmp/build_4cfeda2379ea362c72ac083b57638cce/node_modules/sharp/build'
>
> remote:          TOUCH Release/obj.target/libvips-cpp.stamp
>
> remote:          CXX(target) Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o
>
> remote:        ../src/common.cc:25:10: fatal error: vips/vips8: No
>   such file or directory
>
> remote:         #include
>
> remote:                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> remote:        compilation terminated.
>
> remote:        sharp.target.mk:128: recipe for target
>   'Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o' failed
>
> remote:        make: *** [Release/obj.target/sharp/src/common.o] Error
>   1
>
> remote:        make: Leaving directory
>   '/tmp/build_4cfeda2379ea362c72ac083b57638cce/node_modules/sharp/build'

***Update:***

Try removing sharp from package.json and add it back again using npm install sharp works this time... I still don't know why.

> remote: -----> Installing dependencies
>
> remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
>
> remote:
>
> remote:        > sharp@0.22.0 install
>   /tmp/build_5c8d3b01594e0b86f9d3e0d372534414/node_modules/sharp
>
> remote:        > (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy &&
>   prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
>
> remote:
>
> remote:        info sharp Downloading
>   https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.7.4/libvips-8.7.4-linux-x64.tar.gz
>
> remote:        added 57 packages from 92 contributors and audited
>   20393 packages in 10.683s
>
> remote:        found 62 low severity vulnerabilities
>
> remote:          run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for
>   details
>
> remote:
>
> remote: -----> Build
>
> remote:
>
> remote: -----> Caching build
>
> remote:        - node_modules
>
> remote:
>
> remote: -----> Pruning devDependencies
>
> remote:        removed 606 packages and audited 497 packages in 8.181s
>
> remote:        found 0 vulnerabilities
>
> remote:
>
> remote:
>
> remote: -----> Build succeeded!

Comment: Anyone having the same issue? Or are there any alternative for sharp package for image compression?

Comment: I was able to use sharp in Heroku using official document only, you can use gm(https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm) module as an alternative

Comment: I hope you are not pushing `node_modules` folder as well?

Comment: Thanks @Gomzy for your recommendation, I was able to deploy it on Heroku now using sharp

Comment: @AsgharMusani, thx. I've already added it to .gitignore before pushing it, don't think it's caused by that. Perhaps I'll migrate to AWS to prevent this sort of issue from happening again.

Comment: @user1872384 can you please post a solution, if possible? So that other devs can solve it easily if there are running into the same issue.

Comment: @Gomzy I would like to post a solution, however, I don't have a concrete solution for now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many people with that problem, it's related to libvips as dependency not sharp by itself.

On github in [this issue-comment](https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/issues/18#issuecomment-453933953) the problem is explained:

> The pre-built binaries of sharp are only guaranteed to work with the pre-built binaries of libvips.
>
> If the download of a pre-built binary of libvips fails then sharp has to fall back to attempting to build itself from source.
>
> http://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/en/stable/install/#pre-compiled-libvips-binaries provides information about serving the libvips binaries from a local URL.

The reason why the download is failing might be the cache, or a corrupted download like reported in the above linked issue on github:

> I had to manually remove the `~/.npm/_libvips/libvips-8.7.0-linux-x64.tar.gz` and try again. Seems to be downloaded a corrupted file.

Here is an interesting discussion concerning the same problem related to gatsby, a solution seems not yet existing even the issue was closed (before any comment was made): https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/1754

However if the problem is only related to the download for some reason it's possible to deploy libvips locally like explained in the [manual](http://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/en/stable/install/#pre-compiled-libvips-binaries):

> **Pre-compiled libvips binaries**
>   This module will attempt to download a pre-compiled bundle of libvips
>   and its dependencies on Linux and Windows machines under either of
>   these conditions:
>
> - If a global installation of libvips that meets the minimum version
>     requirement cannot be found;
> - If `SHARP_IGNORE_GLOBAL_LIBVIPS` environment variable is set.
>
> ```
> SHARP_IGNORE_GLOBAL_LIBVIPS=1 npm install sharp
> ```
>
> Should you need to manually download and inspect these files,
>   you can do so via https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases
>
> Should you wish to install these from your own location, set the
>   `sharp_dist_base_url` npm config option, e.g.
>
> ```
> npm config set sharp_dist_base_url "https://hostname/path/" 
> npm install sharp
> ```
>
> or set the `SHARP_DIST_BASE_URL` environment variable, e.g.
>
> ```
> SHARP_DIST_BASE_URL="https://hostname/path/" npm install sharp
> ```
>
> to use `https://hostname/path/libvips-x.y.z-platform.tar.gz`.

So this is a bit background, I'm aware that this can not really be seen as an answer with solution :/

Answer (score 2):

If someone reaches here and didn't found an answer - my issue was that my project was using an **old node version (8.x)**

The **solution** was to install an older version of sharp - The latest one that support 8.x - `"sharp": "0.23.4"`